# Edit an object with unique field: UNIQUE constraint failed: blog_post.title

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to update a record that has the title field as unique. when i edit any other field other than the title i get this error: **UNIQUE constraint failed: blog_post.title**, but when i edit the title, a new object is created. I have looked up examples and work arounds and couldn't fine a suitable approach to resolving it.

so how do i update the record without this error?

```
My database

class BlogPost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    subtitle = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    body = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)

my ulr path

@app.route("/edit-post/<int:post_id>", methods=['GET','POST'])
def edit_post(post_id):
    post_edit = BlogPost.query.get_or_404(post_id)
    edit_form = CreatePostForm(request.form, obj=post_edit)
    if edit_form.validate_on_submit():
    edit_form.populate_obj(post_edit)
    db.session.commit()

    return redirect(url_for("show_post", index=post_edit.id))

return render_template("make-post.html", form=edit_form, is_edit=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think because you're creating a new instance instead of actually updating an existing record, after fetching your record via its id start changing the field values needed and then invoke the save method.

```
post_edit.body="Example"
post_edit.save()
```